# не подписываются ветки git в терминале vs code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Раньше в термнале vs code в скобках подписывалась ветка в которой находишься

Что-то вроде : user:~/project_name (main)$

Переустанавливал систему (ubuntu 22 на неё же) и все настройки git перекинул файлом gitconfig, а настройки vs code синхоризировал через акк, при этом пропала эта крайне удобная подпись с веткой в которой работаешь хотя на ноуте с виндой она есть. Может это настройка git или vs code которая каким то образом не сохранилась?

Comment: Насколько помню, эта настройка не относится ни к git ни к vs code, а к самому терминалу

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883416/adding-git-branch-on-the-bash-command-prompt вот инструкция по настройке на английском

Comment: @ГерманБорисов не уверен что это так, потому-что я не настраивал терминал до переустановки системы, а подсказка ветки была. В любом случае спасибо за наводку

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44627008/6944845

Comment: @tocic тут ршается вопрос отобраения ветки в левом нижнем углу, с этим у меня проблемм нету.

Comment: @legkiy там есть ответы не только про status bar

Answer (score 1):

В общем так и не получилось выяснить почему у меня до переустановки системы ветки подписывались в терминале, а после перестали.

Благодаря наводкам из комментариев смог найти решение (или же это костыль) путём добавления строки:

```
export PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[01;34m\] \w\[\033[01;33m\]$(__git_ps1)\[\033[01;34m\] \$\[\033[00m\] '
```

в файл bashrc.

[Источник](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d6RFFNCAd9w).